# Infinite Probability for single Pendulum

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, physics

My question rather counts to physics, but it still involves statistical mathematics.

Given the equation of motion for a pendulum: $$x(t) = A\,\cos(\omega\,t)$$

This is an object with an $x$-coordinate varying from $x \in [-A,A]$

Now for calculating the Probability distribution, that predicts the probability
of finding the Pendulum in a certain interval I stumbled on the following:

$$ P = \dfrac{2}{T}\, \dfrac{1}{|v|}$$

I'm not sure why this is true but I'm also not familiar with statistics yet.

Anyway, the Probability can be explicitly calculated:

$$P = \dfrac{2}{T}\dfrac{1}{\omega\,A\,|\sin(\omega\,t)|} = \dfrac{1}{\pi\,A\,\sqrt{1-\cos^2(\omega\,t)}}$$

Now by geometry: $\omega\,t = \varphi = \arccos(x/A)$, so finally:

$$P(x) = \dfrac{1}{\pi\,A\,\sqrt{1-(x/A)^2}}$$

The only problem arising: $P(\pm A) \to \infty$. How can it be interpreted the probability distribution  goes to infinity? This would imply that the probability for  finding the Pendulum at $x \in [-A, x_i]$ with $x_i \in (-A,A]$ always is to be infinit, isn't it?

Comment: $P(x)$ is probably a density, so that any probability will be an integral of this which might well be finite , I haven't checked. What is random here though and what is it's density? Time t? The initial value $x_0$?

Comment: First you give the probability for an Intervall, which would be [x1,x2] or the length |x2-x2|, what |v| means in this interval is not clear, v=0 only for x=a or -A

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The initial question is: where is the particle (pendulum) most likely to be found for the given equation of motion. Intuitively I see how this is linked to the inverse of the velocity: the higher it is, the lower the probability to find the particle. I only do not understand how to avoid the probabilty diverging. In fact it should be normalizable to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is
$$ P = \dfrac{2}{T}\, \dfrac{1}{|v|}$$
from ?

If we assume that time $t$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,2\pi/\omega]$. The CDF of $x(t)$ is then
\begin{align}
F(x)&=\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\operatorname{Leb}\Big\{t\in[0,2\pi/\omega]:A\cos(\omega t)\le x\Big\}=\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\Big\{\frac{2\pi}{\omega}-\frac{1}{\omega}\arccos\frac{x}{A}\Big\}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2\pi}\arccos\frac{x}{A}\,.
\end{align}
Where Leb denotes Lebesgue's measure.
The PDF of $x(t)$ is therefore
$$
P(x)=\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2/A^2}}\,.
$$
It is not surprising that this PDF has infinite peaks at $x=\pm A$ because the speed of the pendulum around the maximum amplitudes is slowest.

There is nothing wrong with an infinite probability *density*. The probability of finding the pendulum in an interval $[x,y]$ is $F(y)-F(x)$ and this is finite for every interval.